# How to recognise which reactjs component I am clicking on?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to trigger an event for my reactjs component when it is outside it. Currently I have a collapsible div (blue background) that I want to close once the user clicks outside of it. I have an method pageClick in it to log the event but I can't find a property to use:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.pageClick, false)
}

pageClick(e) {
    console.log('testing=pageClick', e)
}
```

How can I detect whether I am on the component with the collapseclass or not so I can change the state of it?

codepen  [here](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/ZBVdwz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the class of the clicked element to know if it belongs to your collapsible element

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.pageClick.bind(this), false)
  //                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
  //  bind your function pageClick to this so you can call setState inside
}    

pageClick(e) {
    const el = e.target;
    if (e.target.classList.contains('blue')) {
      this.setState({ open: false });
    }
}
```

But this is a poor solution because if you have many different DOM nodes in your collapsible element `e.target` will be the element below the mouse, not the parent `.collapse` element.

So I suggest you to use a library to detect the click outside your element : [react-onclickoutside](https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside) do the job perfectly.

You can see an implementation of your use case using `react-click-outside` in [this fiddle](http://www.webpackbin.com/4kz7cB1EG).

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for click event on the `document` like this -

```
    document.addEventListener("click", this.closeComponent);
```

As an example you can define your collapsible component like this -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class CollapsibleComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        style : {
            width : 350
        }
    };
    this.showComponent = this.showComponent.bind(this);
    this.closeComponent = this.closeComponent.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.closeComponent);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeComponent);
}

showComponent() {
    const style = { width : 350 };
    this.setState({ style });
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    document.addEventListener("click", this.closeComponent);
}

closeComponent() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeComponent);
    const style = { width : 0 };
    this.setState({ style });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div
            id        = "myCollapsibleComp"
            ref       = "ccomp"
            style     = {this.state.style}
        >
            <div className = "comp-container">
                <a
                    href      = "javascript:void(0)"
                    className = "closebtn"
                    onClick   = {this.closeComponent}
                >
                    ×
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```